# PETSc PF objects and user defined functions

Tags: c++, oop, petsc

Presently I am working with a large PETSc program which needs to be modular. I need to use PF objects in PETSc (at least I guess so as I need to pass functions as arguments with enough flexibility with MPI vectors. Is there any other way?) But the PETSc website does not provide much help in this aspect and I am stuck. Any suggestion or example will be appreciated.

Additionally, whenever I use `PFApply` or `PFApplyVec`, it **compiles** but on execution gives something like

> "PFApplyVec() line 202 in src/vec/pf/interface/pf.c
>   Application called MPI_Abbort(MPI_COMM_WORLD,-36453747642)"